# Should I call close method on GoogleCloudMessaging instance explicitly?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Recently, I've noticed, that Google presented new approach for GCM  with using google play service SDK, precisely GoogleCloudMessaging class.
I looked an example at [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-client/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/app/DemoActivity.java?spec=svn44e0469692d7d10a104cd689d3045a56971f90ce&r=44e0469692d7d10a104cd689d3045a56971f90ce) and found out that close() method is not called on GoogleCloudMessaging instance within an DemoActivity at all. 
However, according to [API Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html)

> public void close ()
>   Must be called when your application is done using GCM, to release internal resources.

So, should I call close() on GoogleCloudMessaging instance once I've got registration ID from GCM?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in their demo app they are never "done" using GCM, since they set an expiration time to the registration ID and re-register to GCM when it expires, and they also use it for sending upstream messages to the server.

If you're not going to ever use the GoogleCloudMessaging instance after getting the registration ID, you might as well call `close()`. They don't say what `close` does, but I assume that if you choose to call it, you should nullify the reference to the `GoogleCloudMessaging` instance, and get a new instance if for some reason you need one.

Comment: I want to use GoogleCloudMessaging for new registration flow. I don't need upstream messages at all. And going back to DemoActivity, registrationId will expire after 7 days. Why not to call gcm.close() right after getting registration id? Then when we need to send a message or re-register device, we can get gcm singleton by getInstance method.

Comment: @bsvtag I suppose you can do that (and it should work, assuming they implemented it in a reasonable way), but since I don't have the source code of `GoogleCloudMessaging` class, I can't say what `close` does, and whether there's any meaning to calling it.

Comment: I guess no one, except Google coders, have it :) I'll test it soon and let everyone here knows about results.

Comment: Got it working on production. Mark as answer. Thanks Eran for support!